# Eclipse, "add to working set"

Tags: eclipse

Since Eclipse Mars? there has been always a context menu on projects, to add the current selection to a working set. This option seems to have disappeared in Eclipse Oxygen.

How can I add one or more selected projects to a working set?

[image]

This is how I access the working sets:

[image]

Comment: Which view is this, exactly? Package Explorer, Project Explorer, Navigator, or something else? The entire context menu looks much different than mine. What is "remove from context"? Are you using Mylyn? I never used it, but maybe that's replacing working sets with it's own "context" concept.

Comment: Ah, right, this was the "Plugin Development Perspective". In the Java Perspective it is available, thanks!

Comment: The perspective should not be the problem, but the Plugin Development Perspective seems to use the Project Explorer view as a default for viewing files. If you want to keep using that perspective as a whole, you can just swap the Navigator for the Package Explorer used in the Java perspective.

Comment: You are right, Package Explorer is replaced by Project explorer, which looks completely the same. Was never aware of that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like this is now called "Assign Working Sets..." and is found in the same group as "Refresh" and "Close" in the projects' context menu.

Alternatively, you can just drag & drop the selected projects into the desired working set, provided that you are showing working sets as "Top Level Elements".

(Assuming this is about the "Package Explorer" view; the "Project Navigator" seems not to have that feature, but here you can still use drag & drop.)

Comment: I cannot see "Refresh" and "Close".. See updated question. drag & drop sounds good, but to which window/ view should I drag?

Comment: @kerner1000 I assumed that there are already existing working sets in the package explorer to drag the projects to.

Comment: Yes, there are. But so far I always access them via the tiny triangle menu. See updated question.

Comment: @kerner1000 Sorry, I just assumed you are using the same setup as I am (Package Explorer with Working Sets being the top-level elements)

Comment: I am open for improvements ;) Does Working Sets has a decidated view or something? How can I configure that?

Comment: @kerner1000 You can set the "top level elements" to "working set" (see screenshot in your question), which IMHO is much more useful. Then you can drag and drop projects around and expand and collapse working sets in any combination. But the "add/assign to working set" option seems only present in the Project Explorer.

Comment: Thats awesome! Thanks a lot! Will make my life much easier :)

Comment: If you have too many plugins to drag them, open a project explorer in another Eclipse window (Window/New), and navigate to needed working set there. Then drag between windows. Beware of refresh glitches in Project explorer!

Answer (score 0):

This menu item is still present in Package Explorer (JDT).
No such item is available in Project Explorer (Core).

Please leave a vote for the bug: [Assign Working Sets in Project Explorer, Navigator](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=419935)